# events called from inside another function jQuery with underscore template doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a function which i used to add elements to a list, I want to have events run on interaction with this list, e.g. click. If I do it using the document object it works well however if I use jQuery with underscore templates the element is successfully appended but the  events will not trigger.

```
var addElement = function(parentElement){
    //would work
    this.thisElement = document.createElement('li');
    parentElement.appendChild(thisElement);
    $(this.thisElement).click(function(event){
        alert('working');
    });

    //doensn't work
    this.template = _.template($('#fileListEntity').html());
    var li = this.template();
    $(parentElement).append(li);
    $(li).click(function(e) {
        alert('notWorking');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so with the help of megakorre this is the answer.

```
this.template = _.template($('#fileListEntity').html());
var li = $(this.template({name:doc.name}));
$(parentElement).append(li);

li.click(function(e) {
   alert('click');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

are you shore that template() returns a element. if it returns a string (witch most template system do) that click event wont work.

also there's syntactic errors with not closing the click method.

Comment: I think it might return a string, however because i then use $(li) to get it again jQuery seems to turn it into a usable object when I look in the debugger.

Comment: sorry for the delay... yea but its not the same item that you appended to the parentElement so it dosent mather